# Hijacking the getattr and setattr functions after __init__ completes

Tags: python, python-3.9

I need to intercept setattr and getattr after **init** completion, i.e. if main class doesn't have required attribute, it would look for it in subclass Extra, or when setting attribute, if it's not in main class then setting went to subclass Extra, how to understand that **init** was executed and intercept it only after completion? Here's the code I tried to do it with but it didn't work

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.default_name = "Michael"
        
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if not hasattr(self, key):
            self.Extra.__dict__[key] = value;
        
        self.__dict__[key] = v
        
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if not hasattr(self, item):
            return self.Extra.__dict__[item]
    
    class Extra:
        pass

user = Test()
user.default_name = "Tomas"
user.some_data = "test"

print(user.default_name)
print(user.some_data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct operation attribute dictionary:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        vars(self)['default_name'] = "Michael"
        vars(self)['extra'] = Test.Extra()
        
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key not in vars(self):
            setattr(self.extra, key, value)
        else:
            vars(self)[key] = value
        
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.extra, item)
    
    class Extra:
        pass
```

Test:

```
>>> user = Test()
>>> user.default_name
'Michael'
>>> user.default_name = 'Tomas'
>>> user.default_name
'Tomas'
>>> user.some_data = 'test'
>>> user.some_data
'test'
>>> vars(user)
{'default_name': 'Tomas', 'extra': <__main__.Test.Extra object at 0x000001D5151D6380>}
```

Comment: Note, `vars(self)` literally just accesses `self.__dict__`, going through normal attribute access. It doesn't directly access the dict or anything. It's just hiding the attribute access inside a function.

Comment: @user2357112 I just think the function call is more beautiful than accessing the dunder attribute :-)